# Socket problem when using threading

Tags: .net, sockets, multithreading, socketexception

Can someone please explain me why the following code doesn't work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketThreadingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint("some address"));
            });
            t.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void BeginConnect(IPEndPoint address)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.BeginConnect(address, ConnectCallback, socket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                sock.EndConnect(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected {0}", sock.LocalEndPoint);

                sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));

                Console.WriteLine("success");
                sock.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("send ex " + ex);

                if (sock != null)
                    sock.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is (note the local end point of the socket):

```
Connected 0.0.0.0:28142
send ex System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram
 socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, So
cketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer)
   at SocketThreadingTest.Program.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in Program.cs:line 44
```

Of course when I don't use a thread and call BeginConnect directly it works fine. What's even more puzzling is that adding a Thread.Sleep that is long enough (1 sec) it also works fine.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: The thread you create that calls BeginConnect exits after BeginConnect is called. Do you see any different behaviour if you don't let that thread end (The API docs notes there are issues if the thread calling sock.BeginConnect ends though should only be an issue on a previously connected socket)

Comment: Yes there is a difference. As I said, even adding a small sleep after calling Program.BeginConnect makes this work.
The API doc states: "If this socket has previously been disconnected, then BeginConnect must be called on a thread that will not exit until the operation is complete. This is a limitation of the underlying provider." But as you stated this is a new socket and has not been previously disconnected...

Answer (score 1):

Which makes sense to use separate Thread and BeginConnect?
If you creating separate thread (with Thread pool preferably) why are you using asynchronous connection (in this case separate thread will be taken from the thread pool)?

There are several options:
Use ThreadPool and Socket.Connect

```
class Program {

    static void Connect(object o)
    {
        IPEndPoint address = (IPEndPoint)o;
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(address);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected {0}", socket.LocalEndPoint);
        socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        socket.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5111);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Connect, endPoint);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Use BeginConnect without separate thread.

```
class Program {

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5111));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void BeginConnect(IPEndPoint address)
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.BeginConnect(address, ConnectCallback, socket);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        sock.EndConnect(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected {0}", sock.LocalEndPoint);
        sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        sock.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("send ex " + ex);
        if (sock != null)
            sock.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Use BeginConnect with separate thread:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5111));
        });
        t.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void BeginConnect(IPEndPoint address)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.BeginConnect(address, ConnectCallback, socket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            sock.EndConnect(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected {0}", sock.LocalEndPoint);
            sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
            Console.WriteLine("success");
            sock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("send ex " + ex);
            if (sock != null)
                sock.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of these options but BeginConnect is being called from a separate Thread. This is the design of the application. I'm asking why in this situation I get an error.

Comment: My second example works well... You can change this code to use Thread class instead.

Comment: I changed my example to use Thread class. And it works fine. I think that the problem is not in the Thread class at all.

Comment: It's a timing issue. Your code is exactly as mine and we get different results. the problem is that on my machine the thread exists before the operation completes. see my discussion with nos above.

Comment: OK. I reproduced this behavior on my own machine (now, I'm trying to connect to external host)... and trying to understand why this code doesn't work. Can you use Connect method instead?

Comment: Connect can block for a long time (30 sec on windows by default) and I can't block the thread for such a long time.

Comment: I've noticed, that code works well with ThreadPool instead code with separate thread (with remote host, not local).

Comment: solution: IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(address, ConnectCallback, socket);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

Comment: I've solved it by wrapping the BeginConnect with a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. ugly, but works. thanks for the help.

Comment: But I think you also would add result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(), because thread from thread pool also can be utilize, and in that case you can face very subtle bug! May I change my post to reflect solution there? Or you can reflect it in your own post!

Comment: I don't think you need to add WaitOne or else every call to Socket.BeginConnect on a thread pool thread will need to also to wait which defies the purpose of this async method. And anyways a thread from the thread pool that just called BeginConnect will take some time to be removed from the pool (enough time to let the connect finish), so I don't worry about a bug there.

Comment: hmm.. But if connect would last for 30 sec? This can be enough to remove thread from the pool.

Comment: maybe, but if in 30 sec it can't connect - i say let it fail. I'll take my chances :)

Answer (score 0):

Your IPEndPoint should contain a port -- I'm not even sure how your EndPoint will compile, as it's required.  You can supply the port as the second parameter to your IPEndAddress or modify your BeginConnect method as follows:

```
 socket.BeginConnect(address, [port], ConnectCallback, socket);
```

...where [port] represents the listening port on the Server.

Comment: don't be silly George... of course the code as is doesn't compile. what did you expect me to paste here a real server address?! I thought that writing "some address" is a strong enough hint that this is a place you need to fill before running this code.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that because you are not waiting for the initial thread, the OS is cancelling the I/O request? Windows will cancel the I/O request if the original thread that started the async I/O dies.

In this case, you are calling BeginConnect from a thread, and letting the thread die, so the I/O is getting cancelled. Now, there might be some situation where the I/O might not get cancelled if the thread you started did not actually die by the time you called Send() on the socket.

If you really want this to work, you could try the following variation:

```
       static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate() 
        { 
            IAsyncResult ar = BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint("some address")); 
            // wait for the async connect to finish.
            ar.WaitOne();
        }); 
        t.Start(); 

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 

    public static IAsyncResult BeginConnect(IPEndPoint address) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
            return socket.BeginConnect(address, ConnectCallback, socket); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex); 
        } 
        return null;
    }
```